# How to get total no of updated row count if we have multiple tables inside for loop in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a situation, where the logic DML Statement can be changed at any given time, but other part will remain the same.

In short I have to create a template where I can add 1 or multiple DML Command and post that I need to calculate total No of rows affected by the DML Command.

For current situation I have DML command in For loop and there exist different table inside for loop for update action.

SQL Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_A
  (NAME VARCHAR2(20), ID VARCHAR2(20)
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('SAM',100
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('SAM',100
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('SAM',100
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('JACK',200
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('JACK',200
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('JACK',200
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('HAMES',300
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('HAMES',300
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_A VALUES
  ('HAMES',300
  );
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE TEMP_C
  (NAME VARCHAR2(20), ID VARCHAR2(20)
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_C VALUES
  ('SAM',100
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_C VALUES
  ('RAM',100
  );
INSERT INTO TEMP_C VALUES
  ('KAM',200
  );
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE TEMP_B
(ID VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO TEMP_B VALUES(100);
INSERT INTO TEMP_B VALUES(200);
INSERT INTO TEMP_B VALUES(300);

COMMIT;
```

PLSQL Block :

```
    DECLARE 
   i number(2);
BEGIN
        FOR i in (select ID from TEMP_B) loop
        merge into  TEMP_A c
        using( select i.ID new_id from dual) t
        on
        (t.new_id = i.ID)
        when matched then update set
        c.id = 555;

    merge into  TEMP_C c
        using( select i.ID new_id from dual) t
        on
        (t.new_id = i.ID)
        when matched then update set
        c.id = 555;

        end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line('Total affecetd records are :' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);

END;
/
```

Output :

```
Total affected records are :3
```

Ideally, I was looking to get the output as 12 (Total no of affected rows from both the table inside for loop), but I am getting output for only last query
what shall be done if I need to get the output of all rows affected inside for loop, the DML block can be changed at any given time so I cannot add custom SQL%ROWCOUNT statement and aggregate it I am looking for a generic approach if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE
   I               NUMBER (2);
   AFFECTED_ROWS   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   AFFECTED_ROWS := 0;

   FOR I IN (SELECT ID FROM TEMP_B)
   LOOP
      MERGE INTO TEMP_A C
           USING (SELECT I.ID NEW_ID FROM DUAL) T
              ON (T.NEW_ID = I.ID)
      WHEN MATCHED
      THEN
         UPDATE SET C.ID = 555;

      AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

      MERGE INTO TEMP_C C
           USING (SELECT I.ID NEW_ID FROM DUAL) T
              ON (T.NEW_ID = I.ID)
      WHEN MATCHED
      THEN
         UPDATE SET C.ID = 555;

      AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Total affecetd records are :' || AFFECTED_ROWS);
END;
/
```

AFFECTED_ROWS stores the sum of values of SQL%ROWCOUNT for each statement.

Comment: In case if I have 10 DML statement, then I need to write this again, so I was looking for some generic option.

Answer (score 0):

SQL%ROWCOUNT gives you the rowcount only of the most recently executed statement.
That is the reason you are getting the value of the last query executed in the loop.

You might need to run the %ROWCOUNT after each query execution and store the returned value in a variable. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

> the DML block can be changed at any given time so I cannot add custom
>   SQL%ROWCOUNT statement and aggregate it I am looking for a generic
>   approach if any

I don't think there is any. You probably have to sum up the rowcounts of all your DML statements. And yes you can add a custom rowcount variable and add this up. Why shouldn't you be able to? If you add another MERGE you add another sum := sum + SQL%ROWCOUNT. If you create your DML dynamically in another programming language you create this source code right there, so you don't even have to worry. I can think of any situation where it is not possible to add up the rowcount.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, as mentioned "In short I have to create a template where I can add 1 or multiple DML Command", so DML part will be dynamic rest of part of above block will remain as is, What if I get some DML statement which is unaware of the fact that we are using "sum := sum + SQL%ROWCOUNT" this in template